# lambda function return type not working

Tags: c++, lambda

I have the following piece of code, and find that I'm not able to explicitly convert the output of lambda function into bool. I'm verifying this on the online IDE http://ideone.com/, and I choose C++14.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number = 10;
    int bar = 6;
    auto numberisLarger = [&]() -> bool {return number > bar;};
    bool isLarger = numberisLarger;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I'm getting compilation error as below.

```
error: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'bool' in initialization
     bool isLarger = numberisLarger;
```

I did explicitly convert it to bool, why it isn't working?
Thanks!

Comment: `numberisLarger` is a function.

Comment: Call it like: `bool isLarger = numberisLarger();`

Comment: Voted to close as "a simple typographical error", because all your code is lacking is the parens. If you come from a Pascal background: All functions need to be called explicitly in C(++).

Answer (score 5):

You need to execute the lambda, like you would a regular function.

```
bool isLarger = numberisLarger();
```